# Sequence that satisfies the following:

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\forall \varepsilon>0\ \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow n>N$. $(a\in\mathbb{R})$

Any examples or a general rule would be very helpful.

Comment: Any monotone *bounded* sequence fulfills the above...

Comment: @DonAntonio: There is no sequence that satisfies the condition as written: if $\epsilon>|a_0-a|$, there is no $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ implies $n>N$. Changing the conclusion of the condition to $n\ge N$ at least avoids that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\epsilon>|a_0-a|$; then $|a_0-a|<\epsilon$, but $0\not>N$ for any $N\in\Bbb N$, so no sequence satisfies the condition. Changing $n>N$ to $n\ge N$ in the conclusion of the condition avoids this problem. However, if you do that, then **every** sequence satisfies the condition. Let $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be any sequence of real numbers, and let $a\in\Bbb R$. For each $\epsilon>0$ take $N_\epsilon=0$; then $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ does indeed imply that $n\ge N_\epsilon=0$.

Comment: While this is technically correct of course, somehow I feel there is a more interesting question lurking, though I can't phrase it right now.

Comment: @lhf: I suspect that you’re right, but I’m not going to think about it just now: this version was surprisingly hard to think clearly about as it was!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's more interesting but the question I posted is a small change to the following: $\exists\varepsilon>0$ and $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow n>N$.